# Averaging Parts of An Array In Python

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, average

First time here so hopefully I'm doing this right.

I have an array of daily temperatures for the years 1960-2013 that I read in from a .txt file using np.genfromtxt. I want to take yearly means of the data (i.e. mean for 1960, mean for 1961....mean for 2012, mean for 2013) and am not sure how to only take the average of the subset of the array that I need. My years are also in an array of the same size as my temperature data.

Any best practices on how to go about this?

This is what I have so far. It just having all my data read in.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

city = ['Lubbock.txt','Erie.txt']

for x in range(0,len(city),1):

   data = np.genfromtxt(city[x], usecols=(6), dtype=('S8'))
   data2 = np.genfromtxt(city[x], usecols=(7,8,9))

   dates  = pd.DatetimeIndex(data[:])
   year   = dates.year
   month  = dates.month
   day    = dates.day
   precip = data2[:,0]/10.
   tmax   = data2[:,1]/10.
   tmin   = data2[:,2]/10.
```

Comment: Can you show us the code you have so far?

Comment: You can get a part of an array in python using `array[start:end]`

Comment: Just updated it to show you what I have so far.

Comment: I'd have a look at using [`numpy`](http://www.numpy.org/) and [`pandas`](http://pandas.pydata.org/) to do this. They are great/made for handling data like this and calculating means.

Comment: going on what Ewan said, pandas has a DataFrame from which you can do a groupby to aggregate data up, in this case on the year, and then apply the mean aggregation ( http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/groupby.html#aggregation) . Or without pandas, you can get a unique set of years to loop over and use numpy.mean(numpy.where(data2[:,<year_col_num>] == <year_num>)).

Comment: @Ewan I figure that's my best option. Since each year has a different amount of days, though, I was hoping someone might be able to suggest a function that can grab the elements associated with each year so I can average all those elements together (an automated way of what ronmrdechai was saying).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm glad to see you are using Pandas. It makes the job very easy. You can read your data into a DataFrame using [pd.read_table](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.io.parsers.read_table.html#pandas-io-parsers-read-table), and compute the averages using [groupby](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/groupby.html).

To be concrete, suppose your data file looked like this:

`Lubbock.txt`:

```
foo bar baz quux corge grault date precip tmax tmin
0 0 0 0 0 0 2012-1-1 10 20 30
0 0 0 0 0 0 2012-1-2 11 21 31
0 0 0 0 0 0 2012-1-3 12 22 32
0 0 0 0 0 0 2013-1-1 13 23 33
0 0 0 0 0 0 2013-1-2 14 24 34
```

Then using Pandas,

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

city = ['Lubbock.txt','Erie.txt']

for filename in city:
    data = pd.read_table(filename, sep='\s+', usecols=(6,7,8,9), parse_dates=[0])
    data[['precip', 'tmax', 'tmin']] /= 10.0

    years = pd.DatetimeIndex(data['date']).year
    avg = data.groupby(years)['precip', 'tmax', 'tmin'].mean()
    print(avg)
```

yields

```
      precip  tmax  tmin
2012    1.10  2.10  3.10
2013    1.35  2.35  3.35
```

---

Edit: Using @chthonicdaemon's suggestion, you could simply it even more:

```
for filename in city:
    data = pd.read_table(filename, sep='\s+', usecols=(6,7,8,9), parse_dates=[0],
                         index_col=[0])
    data[['precip', 'tmax', 'tmin']] /= 10.0
    avg = data.resample('A', how='mean')
```

Comment: In fact, you don't need the `groupby` - you can just use `.resample('A', how='mean')`

Comment: I just found that function in pandas today but I'm not too familiar with the package up to this point. This will help a lot too, I'm sure. Thanks!

Comment: @chthonicdaemon: Thanks; that's even better.

Answer (score 0):

Since your data seems to be sorted, you should be able to use [`np.where()`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html), which will give you the indices of an array that meet some criteria. For example,

```
years = range(1960,2014)
tmax_avg, tmin_avg, precip_avg = ([],[],[])

for yr in years:
    toavg = np.where(year == yr)
    tmax_avg.append(np.average(tmax[toavg])
    tmin_avg.append(np.average(tmax[toavg])
    precip_avg.append(np.average(tmax[toavg])
```